# Dynamic web application in eclipse cannot be run on apache server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

The pic explains more.

---

- First I added tomcat 7 server through Window > Preferences(Pic-1).
- Then I created a 'Dynamic Web Project' with tomcat 7 as runtime.
- When I run the project on server Apache Tomcat 7 is absent(Pic-2). Some other server is listed. I opted 'J2EE preview at localhost'.
- Boom, the page shows error 500.

---

What may the possible cause?

!
[image: Pic-1]

[image: Pic-2]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Servers" view: "Window" -> "Show view" -> "Other" -> "Servers". After that, drag your project to the Tomcat server in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

---

- Create a new server with Cntrl+n and select apache tomcat.
- Right click and run on server.
- Now Apache tomcat appears on the list. Choose it and run it.

---

**Happy coding!**